# Default value for hidden field in Django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

I have this Model:

```
class Occurrence(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=True)
    reference = models.IntegerField(null=True, editable=False)

    def save(self):
         self.reference = self.id
         super(Occurrence, self).save()
```

I want for the reference field to be hidden and at the same time have the same value as id. This code works if the `editable=True` but if I want to hide it it doesn't change the value of reference.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the id then? And you can expose it under the name 'reference' by making it a property, but it won't show up in any ModelForms, inlcuding the admin:

```
@property
def reference(self):
  try:
    return self.id
  except AttributeError: #in case the object is not yet saved
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

there are a couple of things I'd like to comment about your code. First of all in *save* it should say **reference** and not **collection**, and the `super` should be indented inside `save`. You forgot to pass the arguments in `super` too. It should look like this:

```
class Occurrence(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=True)
    reference = models.IntegerField(null=True, editable=False)

    def save(self):
        self.reference = self.id    
        super(Occurrence, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This will work always despite the *[editable](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#editable)* value. Editable is there just for the admin. By the way, I assume you are talking about *hiding* reference in the admin. As the id never changes once it's saved you can use it's value instead of the reference one.

Hope this helps.